# How to combine all csv files from the same folder into one data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, csv, merge

I want merge multiple csv files with **same layout** from the **same folder**

example :

csv1.csv

```
      ID, PINA,PINB,PCS

      1,100,200,450

      2,99,285,300
```

csv2.csv

```
      ID, PINA,PINB,PCS

      1,100,200,999

      2,99,285,998
```

out.csv (The file I want make by VB.net)

```
      ID, PINA,PINB,PCS,PCS

      1,100,200,450,999

      2,99,285,300,998
```

my problem code :

```html
 Dim FileReader As StreamReader
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim temp As String
        For i = 0 To LstFiles.Items.Count - 1
            FileReader = File.OpenText(LstFiles.Items.Item(i))
            temp = FileReader.ReadToEnd
            File.AppendAllText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, temp)
        Next
```

Please guide me.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do only the last values in each line vary from each other?  So the maximum entries per line is 5?  Or are you combining "n" files so each resulting line might have "n" entries?  And will the first line always look like that?

Comment: Please explain the logic of combining the csv files. It is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like each line in the input files has an identifier based on the first value in that row.  You want to combine all the numbers after that identifier, from all the files in your ListBox, into one list of numbers that is sorted and has no duplicates.  Then you want to generate an output file that has all those identifiers followed by each set of sorted, unique numbers.

If that is correct, then try this out:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim header As String = ""
        Dim combinedLines As New SortedList(Of Integer, List(Of Integer))
        For Each filename As String In LstFiles.Items
            Dim lines = File.ReadLines(filename)
            If header = "" Then
                header = lines.First
            End If
            lines = lines.Skip(1)

            For Each line As String In lines
                Dim strValues = line.Split(",").AsEnumerable
                Try
                    Dim lineNumber As Integer = Integer.Parse(strValues.First)
                    strValues = strValues.Skip(1)
                    Dim numbers = strValues.ToList.ConvertAll(Of Integer)(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x))

                    If Not combinedLines.ContainsKey(lineNumber) Then
                        combinedLines.Add(lineNumber, New List(Of Integer)(numbers))
                    Else
                        combinedLines(lineNumber).AddRange(numbers)
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error Parsing Line: " & line)
                End Try
            Next
        Next

        Using sw As New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, False)
            sw.WriteLine(header)
            For Each numberSet In combinedLines
                Dim numbers = numberSet.Value.Distinct.ToList
                numbers.Sort()
                sw.WriteLine(numberSet.Key & "," & String.Join(",", numbers))
            Next
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```